# Presenting documents at the US Embassy

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I have some questions I want to ask as regards to US B1 visas or rather US Visas in general.
Now When I get to the Embassy, is it wise when I am being asked questions during the interview that I show documents supporting my travel request to the visa officer? Please advise

Answer (score 3):

1. You should bring all documents that support your case and details the reason for applying for the visa to the interview. Part of the interview process is to check if your case is consistent and to estimate whether you will genuinely seek entry for purposes covered by the visa category. It is always good to have the documents with you to back up what you tell the consulate employee.
2. Normally, you present documents only when being asked, as they know best what they need. If you feel that they may not believe some parts of what you say without a proof, you may want to proactively offer to provide the respective document during the interview.